# Unknown error: Error: Cannot find module 'debug' Require stack (vscode | Mac)

Tags: angular, typescript

While trying to build a new angular project using `ng new (project name)`, I'm getting the error

```
"Unknown error: Error: Cannot find module 'debug'
Require stack:
- /usr/local/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/models/command-runner.js
- /usr/local/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/cli/index.js
- /usr/local/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/init.js
- /usr/local/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng"
```

I tried uninstalling node modules globally `npm uninstall -g npm`  and reinstalling node, but it doesn't seem to help.

Comment: Does [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55948910) help?